# Make listview smaller but not bigger winRT WP8.1

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I have question if is it possible to make listview smaller if the content size is smaller then ListView area but if content is bigger leave ListView as it is?

Currently i have :

```
<Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Zones" Width="400" Margin="0,0,0,57" MaxHeight="240" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">            
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Tag="{Binding number}" Background="#FF0E1D23" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="114" Tapped="Zone_Tapped">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Height="115" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="13" Background="#FFA4EB1B" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name}" Margin="48,10,10,63" FontSize="24"/>
                        <Image Margin="48,64,310,18" Source="{Binding modeImg}"/>
                        <Image Margin="117,64,241,18" Source="{Binding fireImg}"/>
                        <Image Margin="194,64,164,18" Source="{Binding breakinImg}"/>
                        <Image Margin="271,64,87,18" Source="{Binding awareImg}"/>
                        <Image Margin="348,64,10,18" Source="{Binding sabotageImg}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ZoneMenu1" Background="#FF0E1D23" Margin="0,5,0,0"  Height="85" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid Height="87">
            <Image x:Name="Action1" Margin="10,10,320,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/TopNav/_troubles_48.png" Height="67" Width="70"></Image>
            <Image x:Name="Action2" Margin="106,10,225,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/TopNav/_troubles_48.png" Height="67" Width="69"></Image>
            <Image x:Name="Action3" Margin="210,10,123,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/TopNav/_troubles_48.png" Height="67" Width="67"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried *MaxHeight*?

Comment: but the item that is directly under ListView isn't moved acordingly to the listview size

Comment: It may depend on the panel you use and item implementation.

Comment: i added entire grid to the question - could you take a look and maybe see why it's not one under each other?

Comment: Where is the second row in the top grid - to which you put stackpanel?

Comment: so adding Grid.Row="0" and Grid.Row="1" to elements that i want to be after eachother doesnt make them one after another?

Comment: If you want elements one just after another - use Stackpanel. I think you have [some documentation to read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ok now i understand how rows and row definitions work - i thought that one definition is for all the rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your ListView's bottom margin of 57 - make it 0.

What happens in your code is the 57 margin at the bottom forces the bottom of the ListView to always be 57 pixels from the bottom of the screen even when there is not enough content to stretch that far.

Now because the height is set to stretch and the alignment is 'Top' your ListView will shrink if the content doesn't need the full height of the screen when no margin is set (margin of 0,0,0,0 means there is no margin being used, not a margin of 0 pixels...which is weird, but that's how it is).

Comment: I did it but it still isn't working properly ... the StackPanel is displayed at the bottom instead under listview